# What is a use case of `dplyr::select_all` over `dplyr::rename_all`?

Tags: r, dplyr

The **dplyr** package has two functions that both can be used to manipulate the names of columns, e.g.,

```
dplyr::rename_all(mtcars, toupper)
```

and

```
dplyr::select_all(mtcars, toupper)
```

They appear to have been introduced simultaneously in [v0.6](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/blob/v0.6.0-rc/R/colwise-select.R#L34) and their implementations are nearly identical with [the one difference](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/blob/v0.8.0.1/R/colwise-select.R#L59) that `rename_all` passes the argument `strict = TRUE` to the common function they both call. The consequence of this argument is to verify that renaming function(s) are included. Hence, the only difference I see in effect is that

```
select_all(mtcars)
```

is valid, but

```
rename_all(mtcars)
```

is not.  However, as far as I can tell the former is just an identity function, e.g.,

```
> identical(mtcars, select_all(mtcars))
[1] TRUE
```

So what's the point of the `select_all` function then? **Can anyone provide an example use case demonstrating its utility?**

Comment: First thing that comes to mind is when using these inside a function, where you might not know if a renaming function is supplied or not. Of course you could use rename all and catch the error, but it can be nice to be general

Comment: One of the main points of newer changes in dplyr is to make its role as a query builder complete.  select_all() is like select(*).  In many cases this will be from a database table not an existing data frame and then that result will be joined with another table.

Comment: @Elin okay, that makes sense. The [documentation](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/select_all.html) unfortunately only gives examples of renaming and subsetting columns from `data.frame` objects.